# It is possible to pass a code from a web form to a view? (c#)

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have a web application with a contact page that is a web form. Since I can't use the _layout.cshtml as a layout in the Web Form, I was wondering if it is possible to pass the code the web form to a view. I looked over the internet about this but I couldn't find any suitable answer.

I think that, passing the asp.net code to pure html is "possible" but how do I pass the "btnSend_Click" event?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible. You have to generate new codes for View.